# In India, can you do psychiatry after graduating with an undergraduate degree in dentistry?

Tags: graduate-admissions, medicine, india

I am a BDS (dental undergraduate) student in India in final year. I am interested in psychiatry after completing my graduation.

I have heard that I could pursue an Msc in Psychology after my graduation. But, I can't find whether I could do a medical degree in psychiatry. From what I can tell, it might not be allowed.

So: (1) are dental students eligible for medical school in India? (2) if not, is there any way I could become eligible?

Comment: So find a psychiatry course and apply.

Comment: Did you already reach out to a university that offers a MSc in psychiatry and ask them about application requirements?

Comment: @Solar Mike as mentioned in the question, it's not **just** apply. In India, as per my research no university gives admission to a dental student for psychiatry course. Psychiatry is for medical students.

Comment: @JeroendeK there is no university offering Msc in psychiatry but only psychology. For psychiatry atleast to my knowledge graduate in medicine is required not dentistry

Comment: If you apply, they will tell you what is relevant from what you have studied and what you have to cover - we can’t.

Comment: Are you willing to move. The US is pretty lenient about switching fields after a bachelors. But the assumption here is also that the student has certain broadening courses. And yes, psychiatry is a medical profession here also, and has a long educational requirement.

Comment: @Solar Mike but I can't apply for psychiatry in India. That's the whole point. Hence I am asking for any alternative

Comment: @Buffy I am willing but is a dental student eligible?

Comment: Anyone is eligible to apply for anything. But most programs will list some requirements and many programs are very competitive. Of course, you also need to deal with visas and the pandemic.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks. Can you provide some more information. Or share some websites where I can research on my own. Since I have no idea about education abroad

Comment: Sorry, the research is up to you. Google is your friend.

Comment: Don't neglect Canada in your search. Their system is, in some ways, similar to the US, but I don't know if it will help you here. Visa issues might be easier to manage.

Comment: I'm confused about where the US / Canada came into this. Do you want to be a psychiatrist in North America, or in India? In general, medical degrees do not cross national borders so easily. I don't know anything about the Indian system, but it seems to me that if you want to be a psychiatrist in India, you should look for a medical school in India that will accept you (which may require doing additional undergraduate coursework, no idea).

Comment: At any rate, I took a stab at clarifying the question; perhaps this will stop the flood of downvotes. The major unknown to me is whether India's system is such that this question will be answered at the national level (in which case it's a matter of checking the rules) or at the university level (in which case it's a matter of finding a university that will allow it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Psychiatrist and therapists are different things , to become a psychiatrist you will have to clear Neet-ug and Study mbbs for 5 years and then clear neet-pg and take a seat in MD psychiatry, no shortcuts even if you are a BDS

Comment: Yes it is not possible in India unless I pursue MBBS.

Answer (score 2):

Let me summarize.

In the US, an undergraduate degree is not completely specialized. Students study lots of things outside their "major". So, graduate programs don't expect as much specialized knowledge of an incoming student as might be typical in other places.

As most places, psychiatry is a medical profession and the normal path is to get a medical degree, say an M.D., and then specialize in psychiatry beyond that. Medical schools might require a number of science courses for entry, however, especially chemistry and biology. A dentistry undergraduate degree might already include those. Otherwise you have a deficit and a harder path. And the path is quite long in any case. In the US, a psychiatrist would require a license as well as a degree in order to practice. I don't know what that entails, but probably at least an examination. But a researcher, as opposed to a practitioner, might not need a license.

I think the Canadian educational system is similar in some ways to the US system, but I'm not sure it is similar enough to help in your case, especially for medical school. But it might be worth an initial search to discover the options.

But look for medical schools that have an option for a psychiatry specialization.